# a way to pass m2m field and action into a function's parameter? django

Tags: django, function, parameters, model, many-to-many

Let's say I have a model which has a m2m field named `best`.

I know by adding things into the `best` field we can do something like `model.best.add(blah)` or remove `model.best.remove(blah)`

if I have another m2m field named `worst` and I want to make a function which will then use the parameter to define if I should be using the `best` or `worst` field and if the action is `add()` or `remove`

Is if possible?

I already tried something silly such as:

```
def change(field, action, obj):
    model.field.action(obj)
```

of course the above will not work, is there a way to make this work so I do not need to do lots IF if I have LOTS m2m fields in one model?

Thanks in advance for any advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured using `getattr` would work well such as `getattr(model, field)`
this way even if I don't use `action` for the function, still lots less code to write and better if I have new fields added